# Laravel eloquent group by datetime every 10 min. MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to query a column and group the results by datetime, every 10 min.

Example:

```
2019-10-18 15:00 : 10
2019-10-18 15:10 : 3
2019-10-18 15:20 : 4
2019-10-18 15:30 : 1
2019-10-18 15:30 : 32
```

Currently I can group by date, or even by datetime with this:

```
$adminActivities = Activity::whereBetween('created_at', [date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'), date("Y-m-d H:i:s")])
->where('user_id', $data->admin_id)->get()
->groupBy(function($date) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->date)->format('Y-m-d'); 
});
```

**I have a working example in raw SQL in an other function, but I'd like to know how to do it in eloquent**:

```
$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->select('SELECT male,female,date_added
    FROM online_user WHERE date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND NOW() 
    GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) / 600)');
```

**EDIT**

I am currently trying this, but so far no results:

```
$adminActivities = Activity::whereBetween('created_at', [$data->from_date, $data->to_date])->where('user_id', $data->admin_id)
->selectRaw('activity, created_at')
->whereRaw('created_at between DATE_SUB(DATE(' . $data->from_date . '), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) and DATE(' . $data->to_date .')')
->get();
```

`from_date` and `to_date` have this format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`

**EDIT**

It seems `DATE()` just extracts the date, I replace it with `TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: it would look the same cause you will be forced to use `\DB::raw('.....')`. Eloquent is not really made for statistics queries, you might take advantage on its sql injection prevention tools using it but that's about it.

Comment: Okay, thank you N69S